# How to directly send touch events to /dev/input/event?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, touchscreen

I want to send touch events throughout Android system. I'm sending events from a background service. My device is rooted and I've stored my app in /system/app.

I tried `instrumentation and system/bin/input tab`, instrumentation didn't work outside the app, and the second one doesn't generate an error, but does nothing. I've tried injecting directly to /dev/input/event2, but I get no effect.

Here is the code:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {




               try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");//supolicy --live \"allow appdomain input_device dir { ioctl read getattr search open }\" \"allow appdomain input_device chr_file { ioctl read write getattr lock append open }\"");
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("su chmod 666 /dev/input/event2");
                   DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                    String cmd = "su /dev/input/event2  ABS_X "+  xPos + " ABS_Y "+ yPos+ "\n";

                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();
```

I used this website as a reference: https://yhcting.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/linux-writing-input-event-directly/, but I'm not sure if I'm applying it correctly. How can I inject events in /dev/input/event2?

Also, what is /dev/input/eventX? I always see it, but it's not clear whether it's an input node or it's just a general indication of the event node. Finally, how can I know to which event node (event1, event2, etc.) should I send the event?

**EDIT:** I tried su /dev/input/event2  ABS_X  xPos ABS_Y  yPos via adb shell I got a line saying: **unknown username or uid**, what does that mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

"input" is just a sh script in android system.

```
# Script to start "input" on the device, which has a very rudimentary
# shell.
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/input.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.input.Input $*
```

Trace the Java code on how "input" is implemented can be found here:

http://www.srcmap.org/sd_share/4/aba57bc6/AOSP_adb_shell_input_Code_Trace.html

You can also use "sendevent" to inject touch events directly input /dev/input/event0

http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to execute the command to check which event node the device uses, but I got no clear output. I tried that in both runtime.getruntime.exec and adb shell, can you please clarify how to execute the commands in the second link?

Comment: Also, for touch event, you really need to make sure the input even fields are 100% correct.  (It is device dependent.  )  I only use it with the "recorded events" and play it back.  Other wise, the info likely to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, for the root privilege, I need to have su key word before the command and the device must be rooted right? Regarding the second point, do you mean that I need to know whether it's event2 or event4, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `/dev/input/event2` However, to address the primary objective in your first sentence, if you have `adb` available on the shell, you can send touch events via `adb` with commands like:

```
# send the text "password1" into the currently selected textview
adb shell input text password1

# send the enter key
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

More [information for touch devices can be found here](https://source.android.com/devices/input/touch-devices.html). And this is a helpful [list of Android KeyCodes](https://publish.illinois.edu/weiyang-david/2013/08/08/code-numbers-for-adb-input/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm looking to a linux command because I want the android app itself to inject the events without the need to connect it to pc, is this possible? Or, is there a library to run adb commands within app?